# On a metric over m-subsets of [n]

Tags: combinatorics, reference-request, metric-spaces, terminology

Given an integer $n$, denote the set of integers $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$ as $[n]$. For two $m$-subsets $A$ and $B$ of $[n]$, list their elements in the increasing order as $a_1 < a_2 < \dots < a_m$ and $b_1 < b_2 < \dots < b_m$.

Define a metric $d(A,B)= \Sigma^m_{i = 1} | a_i-b_i |$.

I want to know whether this metric has been studied, whether it has a specific name or whether there exist some references on this metric.

What I really want is to find as many $m$-subsets as possible such that their pairwise distance is no less than a given integer $d$.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The metric is essentially the [earth mover's distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth_mover%27s_distance)

Comment: I would say this metric is just the [Manhattan Distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxicab_geometry) in $\mathbb R^m$ restricted to a very special domain.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help.